# How do you call RESTful JSON Web service from within Flash (not Flex)?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, web-services

Is it possible to call a web service from within Flash (using AS3)? Or is the best idea to put the flash movieclip in a Flex container and use the Flex Libraries?

To be clear, when I say within Flash, I mean within the Flash CS4, AS3 programming environment.

Comment: Just to let you know, a Flex application _is_ a Flash application. Flex is just a specific set of libraries and a compiler to turn MXML and AS3 code into a SWF file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to call a JSON-returning RESTful URL from your Flash application. I do it all the time :-)

Just format a standard request using any of the RPC mechanisms (`UrlLoader`, `HttpService`) and decode the returned JSON text using the JSON serializer in [`as3corelib`](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/).

Comment: Sorry Vinay - maybe not clear... I meant from within a flash application. Maybe there's a way of including the relvatn flex libraries?

Comment: Actually, I'm 99% sure he meant Flash; I've done it from a Flash application, too, and the method is the same as a Flex application.

Comment: You can use HTTPService and as3corelib together in flash to do this. URLLoader would work in place of HTTPService if you want too

Comment: How would you access HTTPService from the Flash environment - isn't this a Flex Library?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [as3httpclientlib](http://code.google.com/p/as3httpclientlib/) and [as3corelib](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/) has JSON serialization.